# Translate JavaScript code of RSA encryption to Python

Tags: javascript, python, encryption, rsa

I have [this JavaScript code](https://code.google.com/p/pajhome/source/browse/trunk/crypt/md5/rsa/RSA.js?r=133) to encrypt text using RSA, and I need one que generates the same encrypted message, but that works with Python.

JavaScript code I'm using:

```
var key = new RSAKeyPair(
        "2f9ac975a8a20c1b108e678904b42aa1",
        "",
        "4a5670127da1fd4e2a51685faff367f9"
        );
...
```

I'm having trouble finding an equivalent in Python because the parameter "modulus" present in the code builder in JavaScript, which I did not find in [Python-RSA library](http://stuvel.eu/files/python-rsa-doc/index.html).

I need to rewrite the JS code or is there some simpler alternative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both private and public keys contain the **modulus n**. The public key contains the modulus and the **encryption (public) exponent e**, the private key contains the modulus and the **decryption (private) exponent d**.

So what you have to do is to simply extract the three values **n, d, e** from the keys. Presumably, the python module does that itself.

On how to find the modulus: https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/18031/the-modulus-of-rsa-public-key

General explanation of RSA:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_%28cryptosystem%29